# Plotting with units — getting the right axes labels

Tags: plotting, units

I have a simple example:

```
Plot[UnitConvert[Quantity[x, "DegreesCelsius"], "DegreesFahrenheit"], {x, -25, 300}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

The x-axis has the label $x$ and the y-axis has the label $°F$. What am I doing wrong that x-axis does not get the label $°C$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"DegreesCelsius" does not appear in

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[x, "DegreesCelsius"], "DegreesFahrenheit"]
```

[image]

So you have to be more explicit:

```
Plot[UnitConvert[Quantity[x, "DegreesCelsius"], "DegreesFahrenheit"], {x, -25, 300},
 AxesLabel -> {Quantity["", "DegreesCelsius"], Automatic}]
```

[image]